# Update nowPlayingInfo currentTime after audio loops

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avaudioplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

```
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default);
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true);

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "mp3")!
    let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    player.play();

    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { _ in
        player.play()
        return .success
    }
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { _ in
        player.pause()
        return .success
    }

    var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player.currentTime
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = player.duration
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
```

The above code will loop the audio infinitely. However, on the lock screen control, the track time is stuck at the end of the track (instead of resetting) when the track finishes a loop:

[image]

How do I update the track current time shown by nowPlayingInfo?